# Google Cloud - Communicating between instances

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am in the process of delivering a product.

What my product needs to do is spin up and down multiple instances on google cloud. 
Basically, I have a main instance which I plan to control the rest of them. A 'worker factory' if you will.

What would be a good way to communicate results from the workers back to the main instance.

The actually worker already inserts its results to a sql table also hosted by google, before spinning down.

However I am looking to additionally send off a log file to the main instance. 
What would be the best way of doing this?

p.s - I am not extremely familiar with networking, however I am looking to learn

Answer (score 3):

There are likely many ways to achieve your goal.  One thought is to use Publish/Subscribe.  In this concept, you create a resource called a topic and your *main instance* would register a subscription to the topic.  Now, when your workers wish to transmit information they would executed a publish on the topic.  There is no networking knowledge needed to make this all work.  The topic becomes a centralized drop-off for information published.

Here are the docs on pub/sub:  https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.